# Как правильно провалидировать модель с полем ManyToMany

Tags: django-rest-framework

Есть вот такие модели:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Хочу провалидировать вот такой json:

```
{
  "title": "Новый год",
  "categories": [
    1, # id существующих обьектов Category
    2,
    8
  ]
 }
```

А конкретно, проверить что в categories лежат только int, и что такие обьекты существуют. Попробовал вот такой вариант:

```
class EventSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    categories = RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 3

ser = EventSerializer(data=request.data)
ser.is_valid() #True
```

Но в ser.validated_data отсутствуют категории, только title

Есть мысль, что нужно описать CategorySerializer и использовать его вместо RelatedField, но я пока не понял, как

Comment: Нашел такое решение:
class EventSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'categories')

Поправьте пожалуйста, насколько оно рациональное

Comment: Если Вы нашли решение, то опубликуйте его, пожалуйста, как ответ.